# Нет кнопки закрепить переменную (канцелярская кнопка)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2019

Только изучаю С#. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что сначала я закрепил переменные во время отладки с помощью канцелярской кнопки (когда наводишься на переменную, то она появляется), затем выключил отладку, включил снова, и значения переменных уже не 0, а такие, какими они были на последнем моменте перед тем, как я выключил отладку. И главное, что теперь возле значения переменной появилась кнопки "обновить". Я жму на неё, но ничего не происходит. Ну я и решил нажать на крестик, чтобы убрать эту подсказку. Но теперь наводясь на переменную снова вообще ничего не появляется, что делать?
Пытался гуглить, ничего не нашёл к сожалению

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Visual Studio? Какая?

Comment: 2019. Версия 16.7.2,

Microsoft.net.Framefork 4.8.04084

Comment: Ребят помогите, проблема не исправилась

Comment: это можно сделать только тогда когда вы находитесь в режиме отладки (debug) если вы из него вышли поставить назад не получится, запустите отладку когда дойдете до места своей переменной поставти опять кнопку

Comment: Так в этом то и дело, что в режиме отладки этой канцелярской кнопки нет когда наводишься переменную